# beginner student problem - fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: c++

I am in an intro to C++ class (4 classes in) and just downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio. I am trying to do the first homework assignment and copied the code from my first homework set and tried to build it but I received the problem in the title. Below I've copied my code...it is just a simple addition of two numbers. I did not have this problem when I used the college's computer so I assume the problem is with my install.

```
//HW1.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)

{

    int x, y, sum;

    cout << "Enter two integers..separated by a space: ";

    cin >> x >> y;

    sum = x + y;

    cout << "The sum of the two numbers " << x << y << " is " << sum;

    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you get this program to compile,  link, and run `#include <iostream> int main(){std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";}`? Keep it small when debugging.

Comment: How did you open the file in visual studio? If you just open a .cpp file, you will run into this issue. Make sure it's in a solution/project.

Comment: I created a project, and in that project I created an item and copied/pasted the code into that item, then clicked build.

Comment: Start with just creating a console project. Don't even touch the code you are handed by Visual Studio and see if that compiles. Sounds like nick is on to something as `int main(void) is a valid signature.

Comment: The type of project (as directed by my instructor) was supposed to be an empty project.

edit: the console project was able to be compiled.

Comment: After creating a console project, I copied the relevant code into it and it was successfully compile/built/run. I will ask my professor why it was able to work as a console but not as a blank project. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Are there any other files in the project aside from 'main.cpp'?

Answer (score 0):

The link error sometimes can occur for 2 reasons:

1) You already have the console window open and program running and made changes but didn't save or need to close and recompile.

2) You're not in a project or right project type or the .cpp file isn't fully added to the project. Always make sure you're a the project first.